# how to get current user from realtime database in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new in flutter and still study on it, i got project that the app conncet to the realtime database in firebase and got confuse how to get current user authentication in realtime database in frebase to show the data?

[image: here the database i create]

Answer (score 2):

1. import the dependencies for firebase_auth
2. import the package (`import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';`)
3. ```
   final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
   final currentuser = auth.currentUser;
   ```
4. user this `currentuser` variable anywhere. You can use this to get the current user email id or username anything related which is stored in database